# Check if a number is divisible by 3

Tags: puzzle, division, modulo

Write code to determine if a number is divisible by 3.  The input to the function is a **single** bit, 0 or 1, and the output should be 1 if the number received so far is the binary representation of a number divisible by 3, otherwise zero.

Examples:

```
input  "0":       (0)  output 1
inputs "1,0,0":   (4)  output 0
inputs "1,1,0,0": (6)  output 1
```

This is based on an interview question.  I ask for a drawing of logic gates but since this is stackoverflow I'll accept any coding language.  Bonus points for a hardware implementation (verilog etc).

**Part a (easy):** First input is the MSB.

**Part b (a little harder):** First input is the LSB.

**Part c (difficult):** Which one is faster and smaller, (a) or (b)?  (Not theoretically in the Big-O sense, but practically faster/smaller.)  Now take the slower/bigger one and make it as fast/small as the faster/smaller one.

Comment: why was this closed? see also [build/visualize circuit for checking divisibility by 3](http://codegolf.stackexchange.com/questions/24834/building-circuit-for-divisibility-by-3) / [codegolf.se]

Comment: Umm - 1100 base two is not 6.

Answer (score 12, accepted):

Heh

State table for LSB:

```
S I S' O
0 0 0  1
0 1 1  0
1 0 2  0
1 1 0  1
2 0 1  0
2 1 2  0
```

Explanation: 0 is divisible by three. `0 << 1 + 0 = 0`. Repeat using `S = (S << 1 + I) % 3` and `O = 1` if `S == 0`.

State table for MSB:

```
S I S' O
0 0 0  1
0 1 2  0
1 0 1  0
1 1 0  1
2 0 2  0
2 1 1  0
```

Explanation: 0 is divisible by three. `0 >> 1 + 0 = 0`. Repeat using `S = (S >> 1 + I) % 3` and `O = 1` if `S == 0`.

`S'` is  different from above, but O works the same, since `S'` is 0 for the same cases (00 and 11). Since O is the same in both cases, O_LSB = O_MSB, so to make MSB as short as LSB, or vice-versa, just use the shortest of both.

Comment: yeah, that's what I was looking for.  The solution for MSB and LSB are the same.  Almost no one every figures that out.

Answer (score 28):

There's a fairly well-known trick for determining whether a number is a multiple of 11, by alternately adding and subtracting its decimal digits.  If the number you get at the end is a multiple of 11, then the number you started out with is also a multiple of 11:

```
47278    4 - 7 + 2 - 7 + 8 = 0, multiple of 11     (47278 = 11 * 4298)
52214    5 - 2 + 2 - 1 + 4 = 8, not multiple of 11 (52214 = 11 * 4746 + 8)
```

We can apply the same trick to binary numbers. A binary number is a multiple of 3 if and only if the alternating sum of its bits is also a multiple of 3:

```
4   = 100       1 - 0 + 0 = 1, not multiple of 3
6   = 110       1 - 1 + 0 = 0, multiple of 3
78  = 1001110   1 - 0 + 0 - 1 + 1 - 1 + 0 = 0, multiple of 3
109 = 1101101   1 - 1 + 0 - 1 + 1 - 0 + 1 = 1, not multiple of 3
```

It makes no difference whether you start with the MSB or the LSB, so the following Python function works equally well in both cases.  It takes an iterator that returns the bits one at a time.  `multiplier` alternates between 1 and 2 instead of 1 and -1 to avoid taking the modulo of a negative number.

```
def divisibleBy3(iterator):

    multiplier = 1
    accumulator = 0

    for bit in iterator:
        accumulator = (accumulator + bit * multiplier) % 3
        multiplier = 3 - multiplier

    return accumulator == 0
```

Answer (score 24):

Here... something new... how to check if a binary number of any length (even thousands of digits) is divisible by 3.

[image: divisible-by-3 state machine]

```
-->((0))<---1--->()<---0--->(1)        ASCII representation of graph
```

From the picture.

1. You start in the double circle.
2. When you get a one or a zero, if the digit is inside the circle, then you stay in that circle. However if the digit is on a line, then you travel across the line.
3. Repeat step two until all digits are comsumed.
4. If you finally end up in the double circle then the binary number is divisible by 3.

You can also use this for generating numbers divisible by 3. And I wouldn't image it would be hard to convert this into a circuit.

1 example using the graph...

11000000000001011111111111101 is divisible by 3 (ends up in the double circle again)

Try it for yourself.

You can also do similar tricks for performing MOD 10, for when converting binary numbers into base 10 numbers. (10 circles, each doubled circled and represent the values 0 to 9 resulting from the modulo)

**EDIT:** This is for digits running left to right, it's not hard to modify the finite state machine to accept the reverse language though.

**NOTE:** In the ASCII representation of the graph () denotes a single circle and (()) denotes a double circle. In finite state machines these are called states, and the double circle is the accept state (the state that means its eventually divisible by 3)

Comment: Your FSM works for bits running left to right AND bits running right to left.  Check it out.

Comment: Why is this working? What logic behind that?

Comment: @scarface each node represents the state of the system (remainder 0, 1, or 2). Each time you get a new digit you can work out how the remainder would change with that new digit from each of the states and use that to make the edges in the graph.

Answer (score 9):

Here is an simple way to do it by hand.
Since 1 = 2<sup>2</sup> mod 3, we get 1 = 2<sup>2n</sup> mod 3 for every positive integer.
Furthermore 2 = 2<sup>2n+1</sup> mod 3. Hence one can determine if an integer is divisible by 3 by counting the 1 bits at odd bit positions, multiply this number by 2, add the number of 1-bits at even bit posistions add them to the result and check if the result is divisible by 3.

Example: 57<sub>10</sub>=111001<sub>2</sub>.
There are 2 bits at odd positions, and 2 bits at even positions. 2*2 + 2 = 6 is divisible by 3. Hence 57 is divisible by 3.

Here is also a thought towards solving question c). If one inverts the bit order of a binary integer then all the bits remain at even/odd positions or all bits change. Hence inverting the order of the bits of an integer n results is an integer that is divisible by 3 if and only if n is divisible by 3. Hence any solution for question a) works without changes for question b) and vice versa. Hmm, maybe this could help to figure out which approach is faster...

Comment: Another method which involves only shift and subtract I use:
    (for 57)
    111001 -> 11100-1 = 11011
    11011 ->  1101-1 =  1100
    1100 ->   110-0 =   110
    110 ->    11-0 =    11
    11 ->     1-1 =     0 divisible

    (for 55)
    110111 -> 11011-1 = 11010
    11010 ->  1101-0 =  1101
    1101 ->   110-1 =   101
    101 ->    10-1 =     1 not divisible

Answer (score 8):

You need to do all calculations using arithmetic modulo 3. This is the way

MSB:

```
number=0
while(!eof)
    n=input()
    number=(number *2 + n) mod 3

if(number == 0)
    print divisible
```

LSB:

```
number = 0;
multiplier = 1;
while(!eof)
    n=input()
    number = (number + multiplier * n) mod 3
    multiplier = (multiplier * 2) mod 3

if(number == 0)
   print divisible
```

This is general idea...

Now, your part is to understand **why** this is correct.

And yes, do homework yourself ;)

Comment: NB: multiplier will be always the sequence (1,2,1,2,...).

Comment: Interview question, not homework.  It's just a puzzle, I aleady know the answer.  How about part 3?

Comment: Oops, I meant part c.  Your solution for LSB, converted to any language or even hardware, uses more logic/code/time than your LSB solution.  This is the hard part.  Make LSB as good as MSB.

Comment: @Eyal Buddy, I had given you an efficient solution... This is 99% of the job. Now optimize it. If two bits of memory make difference for you, try to find more tricks ;)

Comment: Part c is the puzzle!  That's the point!  I have an LSB solution as fast as your MSB solution in any language you like.  The puzzle is to find it.

Comment: What, and you expect someone to solve that puzzle, that you happen to know the answer to already, in the middle of your interview while they're applying for a job? Heh. Did you figure it out in that situation?

Comment: Nice algorithm. Can you tell us where it comes from?

Answer (score 4):

The idea is that the number can grow arbitrarily long, which means you can't use `mod 3` here, since your number will grow beyond the capacity of your integer class.

The idea is to notice what happens to the number.  If you're adding bits to the right, what you're actually doing is shifting left one bit and adding the new bit.

Shift-left is the same as multiplying by 2, and adding the new bit is either adding 0 or 1.  Assuming we started from 0, we can do this recursively based on the modulo-3 of the last number.

```
last | input || next | example
------------------------------------
0    | 0     || 0    | 0 * 2 + 0 = 0
0    | 1     || 1    | 0 * 2 + 1 = 1
1    | 0     || 2    | 1 * 2 + 0 = 2
1    | 1     || 0    | 1 * 2 + 1 = 0 (= 3 mod 3)
2    | 0     || 1    | 2 * 2 + 0 = 1 (= 4 mod 3)
2    | 1     || 2    | 2 * 2 + 1 = 2 (= 5 mod 3)
```

---

Now let's see what happens when you add a bit to the left.  First, notice that:

2<sup>2n</sup> mod 3 = 1

and

2<sup>2n+1</sup> mod 3 = 2

So now we have to either add 1 or 2 to the mod based on if the current iteration is odd or even.

```
last | n is even? | input || next | example
-------------------------------------------
d/c  | don't care | 0     || last | last + 0*2^n = last
0    | yes        | 1     || 0    | 0 + 1*2^n = 1 (= 2^n mod 3)
0    | no         | 1     || 0    | 0 + 1*2^n = 2 (= 2^n mod 3)
1    | yes        | 1     || 0    | 1 + 1*2^n = 2
1    | no         | 1     || 0    | 1 + 1*2^n = 0 (= 3 mod 3)
1    | yes        | 1     || 0    | 2 + 1*2^n = 0
1    | no         | 1     || 0    | 2 + 1*2^n = 1
```

Comment: Next, convert all that stuff into a lookup table.  For added speed, have the table look at more than one bit at once.

Comment: I didn't provide any code here.  You're free to implement it any way you want.

Comment: This helped me to build the machine above by myself (the x2 part). Thanks!

Answer (score 0):

Actually the LSB method would actually make this easier. In C:

MSB method:

```c
/* 
Returns 1 if divisble by 3, otherwise 0
Note: It is assumed 'input' format is valid
*/
int is_divisible_by_3_msb(char *input) {
  unsigned value = 0;
  char *p = input;
  if (*p == '1') {
    value &= 1;
  }
  p++;
  while (*p) {
    if (*p != ',') {
      value <<= 1;
      if (*p == '1') {
        ret &= 1;
      }
    }
    p++;
  }
  return (value % 3 == 0) ? 1 : 0;
}
```

LSB method:

```c
/* 
Returns 1 if divisble by 3, otherwise 0
Note: It is assumed 'input' format is valid
*/
int is_divisible_by_3_lsb(char *input) {
  unsigned value = 0;
  unsigned mask = 1;
  char *p = input;
  while (*p) {
    if (*p != ',') {
      if (*p == '1') {
        value &= mask;
      }
      mask <<= 1;
    }
    p++;
  }
  return (value % 3 == 0) ? 1 : 0;
}
```

Personally I have a hard time believing one of these will be significantly different to the other.

Comment: Your solution uses O(n) memory... I mostly sure, that this is not what they expect

Answer (score 0):

A number is divisible by 3 if the sum of it's digits is divisible by 3.

So you can add the digits and get the sum:

- if the sum is greater or equal to 10 use the same method
- if it's 3, 6, 9 then it is divisible
- if the sum is different than 3, 6, 9 then it's not divisible

Comment: However, the number is given in a binary representation. Your method works when the integer is in decimal representation. (And just for fun it can also be made to work hexadecimals)

Comment: it works for binary numbers too.  you have to look at bitpairs in that case:
00, 01, 10, 11.
Add the bitpairs (caution, make pairs from right to left) together and repeat until you have two bits left. if remaining bits are 00 or 11 then the number is a multiple of three and divisible by 3.

Answer (score 0):

```
input  "0":       (0)  output 1
inputs "1,0,0":   (4)  output 0
inputs "1,1,0,0": (6)  output 1
```

shouldn't this last input be `12`, or am i misunderstanding the question?

Comment: Ahh.

For the more general answer, here is a Discrete Finite Automata (general in the sense that a DFA can be created to describe any multiple of n, not just n=3)
Q = q0 ... qn (in this case, n is three)
the transition function, Delta: D (Qn, i) = Q 2n+i mod n
q0 is the accept state.

The key is to recognize that each new digit doubles the number (i=0) or doubles it and adds one (i=1). then, each state qn is a congruence class, meaning: q0 is the number mod n = 0, q1 is the number mod n = 1, etc.

In defense of the interviewing guy, this question actually did help me out with homework.

Comment: no formatting, apologies folks

Answer (score -1):

I think Nathan Fellman is on the right track for part a and b (except b needs an extra piece of state: you need to keep track of if your digit position is odd or even).

I *think* the trick for part C is negating the `last` value at each step. I.e. 0 goes to 0, 1 goes to 2 and 2 goes to 1.

Comment: This is a hint: Your first sentence is wrong.