# How to find remainder without division or modulo operator in MIPS assembly

Tags: assembly, mips, modulo, modulus

I want to find a way to know if an integer is divided by 3 or 7 without using division, because it is very slow in MIPS assembly.

I have done a lot of research but found nothing.

Comment: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/6896533/fast-divisibility-tests-by-2-3-4-5-16

Answer (score 4):

There's a method described by [Granlund & Montgomery](https://gmplib.org/~tege/divcnst-pldi94.pdf) that requires the modular / multiplicative inverse of the (odd) divisor modulo `2**b`. (Some parts of this paper have been improved [recently](https://gmplib.org/~tege/division-paper.pdf))

The divisors: `(d) = 3, 7` (odd numbers) are an easy case. Assuming 32 bit (unsigned) arithmetic, the inverses modulo `2**32` yield `2863311531 (0xAAAAAAAB)` and `3067833783 (0xB6DB6DB7)` respectively. There's an online calculator [here](http://www.hackersdelight.org/magic.htm).

We also need the `qmax = (2**32 - 1) / d` values: `0x55555555` and `0x24924924` resp.

To test a 32 bit (unsigned) number `(n)`, perform a single word multiply - that is, discard the high word of the full 64 bit result: `q = dinv * n`

If `(n)` is divisible by `(d)`, then `(q)` must satisfy: `q * d == n` *and* `q <= qmax`. e.g.,

```
int is_divisible_by_3 (uint32_t n)
{
    uint32_t q = n * 0xAAAAAAAB;
    return (q <= 0x55555555 && (q * 3 == n))    
}
```

Which replaces a division / remainder with a couple of single word multiplications.

And similarly for `d = 7`. Alternatively, a modern compiler like gcc will perform a similar optimization for a constant divisor / modulus, e.g., `if (n % 3 == 0) ...` - in the assembly generated for MIPS, etc.

Answer (score 0):

You can sum the remainders for the individual bits. The `2^n mod 3` goes like `1,2,1,2,...` and `2^n mod 7` goes like `1,2,4,1,2,4,...`.

Use a lookup table to make it even faster.