# Interpreting this assembly code for finding remainder

Tags: algorithm, visual-studio, assembly, hex, division

I have this code for finding multiplies of 3 or 4 below 1000 from a program compiled by Visual Studio 2015.


[image: Find multiplies of 3 or 4 below 1000]

I could identify each part of the loop, and can understand each part except the first one. I get that the higher bits of the multiplication with the multiplicand and 0xAAAAAAAB will be stored in edx, then it is divided by 2 and multiplied by 3, then if the result is same as the original number (in this case i), then it is a multiple of 3. I just don't get why this is true, what's the logic behind it and maybe most importantly where does that 0xAAAAAAAB come from.

This method also seems an overkill to me. Why doesn't it just make a div, and get the remainder from the register?

Comment: Might want to read this: http://steike.com/code/bits/division/  .

Comment: This may also be of interest: https://gcc.gnu.org/bugzilla/show_bug.cgi?id=49552

Comment: `div` is still slower than that whole sequence.  On Intel Haswell, 32bit integer div is [10 uops, with 22-29 cycle latency, and a throughput of only one per 9 cycles](http://agner.org/optimize/).

Comment: Take a look at http://stackoverflow.com/a/22187490/3512216. 0xAAAAAAAB is also called a "magic number".