# Optimized Is divisible by

Tags: c, assembly, optimization, x86, bit-manipulation

Let's say I have the number X and I want to see if it is divisible by Y. What would be the most optimized way to do this?

So far I have:

```
int X = 12;
int Y = 4;
(X ^ Y) & 0b111 ==0    # Check if X XOR Y (mask size Y) == 0
```

Though I'm hardcoding `0b111` (the mask size of Y). By the way, I don't care about the language, I'm just tagging this with C.

---

By the way, using [Compiler Explorer](https://godbolt.org/z/vWcnbW) I get:

```
int is_divisible_by(int x, int y) {
    return x % y == 0;
};
```

```
# -O3
is_divisible_by:
        movl    %edi, %eax
        cltd
        idivl   %esi         # seems to just be doing straight division?
        xorl    %eax, %eax
        testl   %edx, %edx
        sete    %al
        ret
```

Comment: Just do `x % y` and compile with speed optimizations (maybe stop the compiler at the assembler stage `gcc -Ofast -S`): hopefully compiler already uses all the tricks of the trade.

Comment: @pmg exactly -- I mean what would the compiler do at a lower level...

Comment: Surely it depends on the divisor.

Comment: @David542 You can find out by compiling with `-S` and looking at the assembly. Or look at the assembly with a debugger. I would expect to see a division instruction, unless Y is a hardcoded number (e.g. (X % 4) == 0), or the compiler is able to compute the value of Y at compile time.

Comment: @EugeneSh. could you please explain what you mean, or an example where two different approaches would be required?

Comment: Note: if you make the function static (or inline) the function will be possibly be optimised out. (given the predictable/constant arguments)

Comment: FYI Mask in java: `(Integer.highestOneBit(y) << 1) - 1` where highestOneBit needs 6 shrift-rights.

Comment: @David542 I mean that checking if divisible by powers of 2 is way easier than checking if divisible by some other numbers.

Comment: The XOR trick doesn't work for X = 0, 8, 16 etc and anyway if Y is a power of two then the trick is `(X & (Y - 1)) == 0`

Comment: If Y is known but not a power of two then [this answer applies](https://stackoverflow.com/a/49264279/555045) (with the multiplication by the modular inverse and sometimes bitwise rotate). If Y is not known, well, bad luck.

Comment: I really doubt there is a universal method not involving division (or some kind of it's indirect implementation such as repeated subtraction)

Answer (score 9, accepted):

The compiler will use different algorithms depending on arguments. If some are constant expressions or can be predicted before the call it will use much faster way of doing it.

```
int is_divisible_by(const int x, const int y) {
    return !(x % y);
};

int case1(void)
{
    return is_divisible_by(6,3);
}

int case2(int x)
{
    return is_divisible_by(x,2);
}

int case3(int x)
{
    return is_divisible_by(x,5);
}

int case4(int x)
{
    return is_divisible_by(x,255);
}

int case5(int x)
{
    return is_divisible_by(x,32);
}


int case6(int x, int y)
{
    return is_divisible_by(x,y);
}
```

```
is_divisible_by:
        mov     eax, edi
        cdq
        idiv    esi
        xor     eax, eax
        test    edx, edx
        sete    al
        ret
case1:
        mov     eax, 1
        ret
case2:
        mov     eax, edi
        not     eax
        and     eax, 1
        ret
case3:
        imul    edi, edi, -858993459
        xor     eax, eax
        add     edi, 429496729
        cmp     edi, 858993458
        setbe   al
        ret
case4:
        imul    edi, edi, -16843009
        xor     eax, eax
        add     edi, 8421504
        cmp     edi, 16843008
        setbe   al
        ret
case5:
        xor     eax, eax
        and     edi, 31
        sete    al
        ret
case6:
        mov     eax, edi
        cdq
        idiv    esi
        xor     eax, eax
        test    edx, edx
        sete    al
        ret
```

https://godbolt.org/z/9cxEfe

Comment: Nice illustration