# Make sure if a value in register is a multiple of 3 in AVR Studio using assembly

Tags: assembly, bit-manipulation, avr, integer-division

I want to make sure if a number in register is a multiple of 3 using AVR Studio and assembly language but on AVR ATmega 8515 so there is no div instruction/syntax

I already tried a couple method like adding the register and 0b0011 expecting the carry flag would be set, but it isn't.

Comment: Hardware division is a slow way to test for divisibility by 3 anyway.  See [Fast divisibility tests (by 2,3,4,5,.., 16)?](https://stackoverflow.com/q/6896533) for multiplicative constants.  Hopefully a narrower version of that is possible with smaller constants for 16-bit.  For 8-bit a lookup table is possible if you need max speed on AVR, otherwise multiply (possibly manually with shift-and-add.)

Comment: So you want to multiply with 3? Or divide by 3? I am confised, maybe cou can be more clear about what you want to achieve, and for which data types.

Comment: Please provide enough code so others can better understand or reproduce the problem.

Answer (score 2):

So a straight forward way is to let avr-gcc compile a piece of C code, and then peek at the assembly<sup>1</sup> it generates:

For an 8-bit, unsigned value consider the following C99:

```cpp
#include <stdint.h>
#include <stdbool.h>

bool is_udiv3_8 (uint8_t x)
{
    return x % 3 == 0;
}
```

With something like

```
> avr-gcc x.c -mmcu=atmega8515 -O2 -S
```

we get `x.s` (alternatively, add `-save-temps` to an ordinary compilation and then intercept the *.s file).

```lisp
is_udiv3_8:
    ldi r25,lo8(-85) ;1
    mul r24,r25      ;2
    mov r25,r1       ;3
    clr __zero_reg__ ;4
    lsr r25          ;5
    mov r18,r25      ;6
    lsl r18          ;7
    add r25,r18      ;8
    ldi r18,lo8(1)   ;9
    cpse r24,r25     ;10
    ldi r18,0        ;11
    mov r24,r18      ;12
    ret
```

What avr-gcc does is to multiply the input with -256/3 and takes the high byte of the product as the quotient after dividing by 3.  After some adjustments, it returns in R24 True (1) if the input was divisible by 3 and False (0), otherwise.

You can extend this to 16-bit values, but you'll need the high word of a 16×16=32 multiplication.

At that point you remember<sup>2</sup> that a natural number N written in base B is divisible by B+1 iff the alternating cross sum over the digits in base B is divisible by B+1.

For example in base B=2: A natural number N is divisible by 3 iff the alternating cross sum of the bits of N is divisible by 3.

Written in assembly:

- First a loop over the bits to get the binary cross sum.  For speed you would unroll that loop which would get 8 `sbrs`s and 8 `sbrc`s.
- The cross sum q satisfies -8 <= q <= 8. Negating does not change whether q is divisible by 3, thus continue with |q| which is non-negative.
- Subtract 3 until the result is 0, 1 or 2.
- Return True if the value reached 0, and False otherwise (it reached 1 or 2).

```lisp
.text
.global is_div3_asm

is_div3_asm:
    ;; R26 holds R25:R24 mod 3
    clr r26
.Loop_bits:
    ;; Loop over all bits of R25:R24 to compute the alternating cross sum
    ;; over the binary digits of R25:R24.
    sbiw r24, 0
    breq .Loop_done
    sbrc r24, 0 $ inc  r26
    sbrc r24, 1 $ dec  r26
    lsr  r25 $ ror r24
    lsr  r25 $ ror r24
    rjmp .Loop_bits
.Loop_done:
    ;; r26 = abs(r26)
    sbrc r26, 7
    neg  r26
    ;; Now we have 0 <= r26 <= 8, so reduce to r26 < 3...
    cpi  r26, 3
    brlt .Ltobool
    subi r26, 3
    ;; ...now we have 0 <= r26 <= 5, so at most one more sub 3 will do.
    cpi  r26, 3
    brlt .Ltobool
    subi r26, 3
.Ltobool:
    ;; Return a bool in R24 as of avr-gcc ABI.
    ldi r24, 1                  ; True
    cpi r26, 0
    breq .Ldone
    ldi r24, 0                  ; False
.Ldone:    
    ret
```

This function complies to the avr-gcc ABI and [calling convention](https://gcc.gnu.org/wiki/avr-gcc#Calling_Convention). You can use it from C/C++ by means of prototype

```cpp
extern bool is_div3_asm (uint16_t); // C
extern "C" bool is_div3_asm (uint16_t); // C++
```

---

<sup>**1**</sup>Note that there are different assembly dialects. This answer uses the GNU assemlby dialect because it is compatible with the GNU assembler and produced by avr-gcc and avr-g++.

<sup>**2**</sup>The result is actually stronger: A natural number N is in the same rest class modulo B+1 like the alternating cross sum of N in base B. The proof is just a few lines of modular arithmetic and boils down to B ≡ -1 mod B+1.

Answer (score 1):

This is just a bit of a comment and elaboration on [@emacs drives me nuts' answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/76067066/182675) but is too long and complex to be a Stackoverflow comment, therefore this is a Community wiki Stackoverflow answer.

I have compiled 8, 16, 24, and 32 bit versions on [godbolt.org](https://godbolt.org/#g:!((g:!((g:!((h:codeEditor,i:(filename:%271%27,fontScale:14,fontUsePx:%270%27,j:1,lang:___c,selection:(endColumn:1,endLineNumber:14,positionColumn:1,positionLineNumber:14,selectionStartColumn:1,selectionStartLineNumber:14,startColumn:1,startLineNumber:14),source:%27%23include+%3Cstdbool.h%3E%0A%23include+%3Cstdint.h%3E%0A%0A%23if+(defined(__AVR)+%26%26+defined(__GNUC__)+%26%26+((__GNUC__+%3E+4)+%7C%7C+((__GNUC__+%3D%3D+4)+%26%26+(__GNUC_MINOR__+%3E%3D+7))))%0A%23define+HAVE_INT24_TYPES%0A%23endif%0A%0Abool+is_udiv8_by_3+(+uint8_t+x)+%7B+return+((x%253)+%3D%3D+0)%3B+%7D%0Abool+is_udiv16_by_3(uint16_t+x)+%7B+return+((x%253)+%3D%3D+0)%3B+%7D%0A%23ifdef+HAVE_INT24_TYPES%0Abool+is_udiv24_by_3(__uint24+x)+%7B+return+((x%253)+%3D%3D+0)%3B+%7D%0A%23endif%0Abool+is_udiv32_by_3(uint32_t+x)+%7B+return+((x%253)+%3D%3D+0)%3B+%7D%0A%27),l:%275%27,n:%270%27,o:%27C+source+%231%27,t:%270%27)),k:33.032083498952225,l:%274%27,n:%270%27,o:%27%27,s:0,t:%270%27),(g:!((h:compiler,i:(compiler:cavrg1220,deviceViewOpen:%271%27,filters:(b:%270%27,binary:%271%27,binaryObject:%271%27,commentOnly:%270%27,demangle:%270%27,directives:%270%27,execute:%271%27,intel:%270%27,libraryCode:%271%27,trim:%271%27),flagsViewOpen:%271%27,fontScale:14,fontUsePx:%270%27,j:1,lang:___c,libs:!(),options:%27-std%3Dc99++-O2+-g+-mmcu%3Datmega8515%27,selection:(endColumn:1,endLineNumber:1,positionColumn:1,positionLineNumber:1,selectionStartColumn:1,selectionStartLineNumber:1,startColumn:1,startLineNumber:1),source:1),l:%275%27,n:%270%27,o:%27+AVR+gcc+12.2.0+(Editor+%231)%27,t:%270%27)),k:33.63458316771446,l:%274%27,m:100,n:%270%27,o:%27%27,s:0,t:%270%27),(g:!((h:compiler,i:(compiler:cavrg540,deviceViewOpen:%271%27,filters:(b:%270%27,binary:%271%27,binaryObject:%271%27,commentOnly:%270%27,demangle:%270%27,directives:%270%27,execute:%271%27,intel:%270%27,libraryCode:%270%27,trim:%271%27),flagsViewOpen:%271%27,fontScale:14,fontUsePx:%270%27,j:2,lang:___c,libs:!(),options:%27-std%3Dc99+-O2+-g+-mmcu%3Datmega8515%27,selection:(endColumn:1,endLineNumber:1,positionColumn:1,positionLineNumber:1,selectionStartColumn:1,selectionStartLineNumber:1,startColumn:1,startLineNumber:1),source:1),l:%275%27,n:%270%27,o:%27+AVR+gcc+5.4.0+(Editor+%231)%27,t:%270%27)),k:33.33333333333333,l:%274%27,n:%270%27,o:%27%27,s:0,t:%270%27)),l:%272%27,n:%270%27,o:%27%27,t:%270%27)),version:4) with different versions of avr-gcc (12.2.0 and 5.4.0) with the same compile options (`-std=c99  -O2 -g -mmcu=atmega8515`). It turns out the code produced by avr-gcc 12.2.0 is significantly shorter than what avr-gcc 5.4.0 produces.

As [@emacs drives me nuts' answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/76067066/182675) works off the relatively complicated code from avr-gcc 5.4.0, it may be useful to take a look at the simpler code from 12.2.0 as well.

The `uint8_t` variant from avr-gcc 5.4.0 appears to be what [@emacs drives me nuts' answer](https://godbolt.org/#g:!((g:!((g:!((h:codeEditor,i:(filename:%271%27,fontScale:14,fontUsePx:%270%27,j:1,lang:___c,selection:(endColumn:1,endLineNumber:14,positionColumn:1,positionLineNumber:14,selectionStartColumn:1,selectionStartLineNumber:14,startColumn:1,startLineNumber:14),source:%27%23include+%3Cstdbool.h%3E%0A%23include+%3Cstdint.h%3E%0A%0A%23if+(defined(__AVR)+%26%26+defined(__GNUC__)+%26%26+((__GNUC__+%3E+4)+%7C%7C+((__GNUC__+%3D%3D+4)+%26%26+(__GNUC_MINOR__+%3E%3D+7))))%0A%23define+HAVE_INT24_TYPES%0A%23endif%0A%0Abool+is_udiv8_by_3+(+uint8_t+x)+%7B+return+((x%253)+%3D%3D+0)%3B+%7D%0Abool+is_udiv16_by_3(uint16_t+x)+%7B+return+((x%253)+%3D%3D+0)%3B+%7D%0A%23ifdef+HAVE_INT24_TYPES%0Abool+is_udiv24_by_3(__uint24+x)+%7B+return+((x%253)+%3D%3D+0)%3B+%7D%0A%23endif%0Abool+is_udiv32_by_3(uint32_t+x)+%7B+return+((x%253)+%3D%3D+0)%3B+%7D%0A%27),l:%275%27,n:%270%27,o:%27C+source+%231%27,t:%270%27)),k:33.032083498952225,l:%274%27,n:%270%27,o:%27%27,s:0,t:%270%27),(g:!((h:compiler,i:(compiler:cavrg1220,deviceViewOpen:%271%27,filters:(b:%270%27,binary:%271%27,binaryObject:%271%27,commentOnly:%270%27,demangle:%270%27,directives:%270%27,execute:%271%27,intel:%270%27,libraryCode:%271%27,trim:%271%27),flagsViewOpen:%271%27,fontScale:14,fontUsePx:%270%27,j:1,lang:___c,libs:!(),options:%27-std%3Dc99++-O2+-g+-mmcu%3Datmega8515%27,selection:(endColumn:1,endLineNumber:1,positionColumn:1,positionLineNumber:1,selectionStartColumn:1,selectionStartLineNumber:1,startColumn:1,startLineNumber:1),source:1),l:%275%27,n:%270%27,o:%27+AVR+gcc+12.2.0+(Editor+%231)%27,t:%270%27)),k:33.63458316771446,l:%274%27,m:100,n:%270%27,o:%27%27,s:0,t:%270%27),(g:!((h:compiler,i:(compiler:cavrg540,deviceViewOpen:%271%27,filters:(b:%270%27,binary:%271%27,binaryObject:%271%27,commentOnly:%270%27,demangle:%270%27,directives:%270%27,execute:%271%27,intel:%270%27,libraryCode:%270%27,trim:%271%27),flagsViewOpen:%271%27,fontScale:14,fontUsePx:%270%27,j:2,lang:___c,libs:!(),options:%27-std%3Dc99+-O2+-g+-mmcu%3Datmega8515%27,selection:(endColumn:1,endLineNumber:1,positionColumn:1,positionLineNumber:1,selectionStartColumn:1,selectionStartLineNumber:1,startColumn:1,startLineNumber:1),source:1),l:%275%27,n:%270%27,o:%27+AVR+gcc+5.4.0+(Editor+%231)%27,t:%270%27)),k:33.33333333333333,l:%274%27,n:%270%27,o:%27%27,s:0,t:%270%27)),l:%272%27,n:%270%27,o:%27%27,t:%270%27)),version:4) works on:

```
is_udiv8_by_3:
        ldi r25,lo8(-85)  /* 1 */
        mul r24,r25       /* 2 */
        mov r25,r1        /* 1 */
        clr __zero_reg__  /* 1 */
        lsr r25           /* 1 */
        mov r18,r25       /* 1 */
        lsl r18           /* 1 */
        add r25,r18       /* 1 */
        ldi r18,lo8(1)    /* 1 */
        cpse r24,r25      /* 1 */
        ldi r18,0         /* 1 */
        mov r24,r18       /* 1 */
        ret               /* 13 cycles plus ret */
```

`uint8_t` variant from avr-gcc 12.2.0:

```
is_udiv8_by_3:
        ldi r25,lo8(-85)  /* 1 */
        mul r24,r25       /* 2 */
        mov r25,r0        /* 1 */
        clr r1            /* 1 */
        ldi r24,lo8(1)    /* 1 */
        cpi r25,lo8(86)   /* 1 */
        brlo .L2          /* 2/1 */
        ldi r24,0         /* -/1 */
.L2:
        ret               /* 9 cycles plus ret */
```

The `uint16_t` variant from avr-gcc 12.2.0 is not significantly longer than the `uint8_t` variant from avr-gcc 5.4.0:

```
is_udiv16_by_3:
        ldi r20,lo8(-85)  /* 1 */
        ldi r21,lo8(-86)  /* 1 */
        mul r24,r20       /* 2 */
        movw r18,r0       /* 2 */
        mul r24,r21       /* 2 */
        add r19,r0        /* 1 */
        mul r25,r20       /* 2 */
        add r19,r0        /* 1 */
        clr r1            /* 1 */
        ldi r24,lo8(1)    /* 1 */
        cpi r18,86        /* 1 */
        sbci r19,85       /* 1 */
        brlo .L5          /* 2/1 */
        ldi r24,0         /* -/1 */
.L5:
        ret               /* 18 cycles plus ret */
```

BTW, the cycle count of the `is_div3_asm` function from [@emacs drives me nuts' answer](https://godbolt.org/#g:!((g:!((g:!((h:codeEditor,i:(filename:%271%27,fontScale:14,fontUsePx:%270%27,j:1,lang:___c,selection:(endColumn:1,endLineNumber:14,positionColumn:1,positionLineNumber:14,selectionStartColumn:1,selectionStartLineNumber:14,startColumn:1,startLineNumber:14),source:%27%23include+%3Cstdbool.h%3E%0A%23include+%3Cstdint.h%3E%0A%0A%23if+(defined(__AVR)+%26%26+defined(__GNUC__)+%26%26+((__GNUC__+%3E+4)+%7C%7C+((__GNUC__+%3D%3D+4)+%26%26+(__GNUC_MINOR__+%3E%3D+7))))%0A%23define+HAVE_INT24_TYPES%0A%23endif%0A%0Abool+is_udiv8_by_3+(+uint8_t+x)+%7B+return+((x%253)+%3D%3D+0)%3B+%7D%0Abool+is_udiv16_by_3(uint16_t+x)+%7B+return+((x%253)+%3D%3D+0)%3B+%7D%0A%23ifdef+HAVE_INT24_TYPES%0Abool+is_udiv24_by_3(__uint24+x)+%7B+return+((x%253)+%3D%3D+0)%3B+%7D%0A%23endif%0Abool+is_udiv32_by_3(uint32_t+x)+%7B+return+((x%253)+%3D%3D+0)%3B+%7D%0A%27),l:%275%27,n:%270%27,o:%27C+source+%231%27,t:%270%27)),k:33.032083498952225,l:%274%27,n:%270%27,o:%27%27,s:0,t:%270%27),(g:!((h:compiler,i:(compiler:cavrg1220,deviceViewOpen:%271%27,filters:(b:%270%27,binary:%271%27,binaryObject:%271%27,commentOnly:%270%27,demangle:%270%27,directives:%270%27,execute:%271%27,intel:%270%27,libraryCode:%271%27,trim:%271%27),flagsViewOpen:%271%27,fontScale:14,fontUsePx:%270%27,j:1,lang:___c,libs:!(),options:%27-std%3Dc99++-O2+-g+-mmcu%3Datmega8515%27,selection:(endColumn:1,endLineNumber:1,positionColumn:1,positionLineNumber:1,selectionStartColumn:1,selectionStartLineNumber:1,startColumn:1,startLineNumber:1),source:1),l:%275%27,n:%270%27,o:%27+AVR+gcc+12.2.0+(Editor+%231)%27,t:%270%27)),k:33.63458316771446,l:%274%27,m:100,n:%270%27,o:%27%27,s:0,t:%270%27),(g:!((h:compiler,i:(compiler:cavrg540,deviceViewOpen:%271%27,filters:(b:%270%27,binary:%271%27,binaryObject:%271%27,commentOnly:%270%27,demangle:%270%27,directives:%270%27,execute:%271%27,intel:%270%27,libraryCode:%270%27,trim:%271%27),flagsViewOpen:%271%27,fontScale:14,fontUsePx:%270%27,j:2,lang:___c,libs:!(),options:%27-std%3Dc99+-O2+-g+-mmcu%3Datmega8515%27,selection:(endColumn:1,endLineNumber:1,positionColumn:1,positionLineNumber:1,selectionStartColumn:1,selectionStartLineNumber:1,startColumn:1,startLineNumber:1),source:1),l:%275%27,n:%270%27,o:%27+AVR+gcc+5.4.0+(Editor+%231)%27,t:%270%27)),k:33.33333333333333,l:%274%27,n:%270%27,o:%27%27,s:0,t:%270%27)),l:%272%27,n:%270%27,o:%27%27,t:%270%27)),version:4) depends on the input value, and goes over 18 cycles even for a single iteration of the `.Loop_bits` loop.

When increasing the type size to 24bit (the `__uint24` variant) and 32bit, avr-gcc 12.2.0 finally starts calls a division function `__udivmodpsi4`:

```
is_udiv24_by_3:
        ldi r18,lo8(3)
        ldi r19,0
        ldi r20,0
        rcall __udivmodpsi4
        ldi r24,lo8(1)
        or r18,r19
        or r18,r20
        breq .L7
        ldi r24,0
.L7:
        ret
```

The `uint32_t` calls a different division function `__udivmodsi4` and is a lot longer as well:

```
is_udiv32_by_3:
        push r28
        push r29
        rcall .
        rcall .
        in r28,__SP_L__
        in r29,__SP_H__
        ldi r18,lo8(3)
        ldi r19,0
        ldi r20,0
        ldi r21,0
        rcall __udivmodsi4
        std Y+1,r22
        std Y+2,r23
        std Y+3,r24
        std Y+4,r25
        ldi r24,lo8(1)
        ldd r18,Y+1
        ldd r19,Y+2
        ldd r20,Y+3
        ldd r21,Y+4
        or r18,r19
        or r18,r20
        or r18,r21
        breq .L12
        ldi r24,0
.L12:
        pop __tmp_reg__
        pop __tmp_reg__
        pop __tmp_reg__
        pop __tmp_reg__
        pop r29
        pop r28
        ret
```

(gcc 5.4.0, 12.3 and 13 produce much more understandable code, especially clued in using `return 0 == (int8_t)(x % 3);`:

```
is_udiv32_by_3:
        ldi r18,lo8(3)
        ldi r19,0
        ldi r20,0
        ldi r21,0
        rcall __udivmodsi4
        ldi r24,lo8(1)
        cpse r22,__zero_reg__
        ldi r24,0
        ret
```

)
So looking for other algorithms like the alternate cross sum algorithm from [@emacs drives me nuts' answer](https://godbolt.org/#g:!((g:!((g:!((h:codeEditor,i:(filename:%271%27,fontScale:14,fontUsePx:%270%27,j:1,lang:___c,selection:(endColumn:1,endLineNumber:14,positionColumn:1,positionLineNumber:14,selectionStartColumn:1,selectionStartLineNumber:14,startColumn:1,startLineNumber:14),source:%27%23include+%3Cstdbool.h%3E%0A%23include+%3Cstdint.h%3E%0A%0A%23if+(defined(__AVR)+%26%26+defined(__GNUC__)+%26%26+((__GNUC__+%3E+4)+%7C%7C+((__GNUC__+%3D%3D+4)+%26%26+(__GNUC_MINOR__+%3E%3D+7))))%0A%23define+HAVE_INT24_TYPES%0A%23endif%0A%0Abool+is_udiv8_by_3+(+uint8_t+x)+%7B+return+((x%253)+%3D%3D+0)%3B+%7D%0Abool+is_udiv16_by_3(uint16_t+x)+%7B+return+((x%253)+%3D%3D+0)%3B+%7D%0A%23ifdef+HAVE_INT24_TYPES%0Abool+is_udiv24_by_3(__uint24+x)+%7B+return+((x%253)+%3D%3D+0)%3B+%7D%0A%23endif%0Abool+is_udiv32_by_3(uint32_t+x)+%7B+return+((x%253)+%3D%3D+0)%3B+%7D%0A%27),l:%275%27,n:%270%27,o:%27C+source+%231%27,t:%270%27)),k:33.032083498952225,l:%274%27,n:%270%27,o:%27%27,s:0,t:%270%27),(g:!((h:compiler,i:(compiler:cavrg1220,deviceViewOpen:%271%27,filters:(b:%270%27,binary:%271%27,binaryObject:%271%27,commentOnly:%270%27,demangle:%270%27,directives:%270%27,execute:%271%27,intel:%270%27,libraryCode:%271%27,trim:%271%27),flagsViewOpen:%271%27,fontScale:14,fontUsePx:%270%27,j:1,lang:___c,libs:!(),options:%27-std%3Dc99++-O2+-g+-mmcu%3Datmega8515%27,selection:(endColumn:1,endLineNumber:1,positionColumn:1,positionLineNumber:1,selectionStartColumn:1,selectionStartLineNumber:1,startColumn:1,startLineNumber:1),source:1),l:%275%27,n:%270%27,o:%27+AVR+gcc+12.2.0+(Editor+%231)%27,t:%270%27)),k:33.63458316771446,l:%274%27,m:100,n:%270%27,o:%27%27,s:0,t:%270%27),(g:!((h:compiler,i:(compiler:cavrg540,deviceViewOpen:%271%27,filters:(b:%270%27,binary:%271%27,binaryObject:%271%27,commentOnly:%270%27,demangle:%270%27,directives:%270%27,execute:%271%27,intel:%270%27,libraryCode:%270%27,trim:%271%27),flagsViewOpen:%271%27,fontScale:14,fontUsePx:%270%27,j:2,lang:___c,libs:!(),options:%27-std%3Dc99+-O2+-g+-mmcu%3Datmega8515%27,selection:(endColumn:1,endLineNumber:1,positionColumn:1,positionLineNumber:1,selectionStartColumn:1,selectionStartLineNumber:1,startColumn:1,startLineNumber:1),source:1),l:%275%27,n:%270%27,o:%27+AVR+gcc+5.4.0+(Editor+%231)%27,t:%270%27)),k:33.33333333333333,l:%274%27,n:%270%27,o:%27%27,s:0,t:%270%27)),l:%272%27,n:%270%27,o:%27%27,t:%270%27)),version:4) or the [Fast divisibility tests (by 2,3,4,5,.., 16)?](https://stackoverflow.com/a/49264279) @Peter Cordes links to look interesting for integers sizes above 16 bits only.

Code sizes and loop cycles would need to be considered more carefully.

Comment: GCC5.4 predates Cassio Neri's improved algorithm ([Fast divisibility tests (by 2,3,4,5,.., 16)?](https://stackoverflow.com/a/49264279)) which made it into GCC9 in oct 2018.

Comment: Notice that for code size, you also have to take into account the code that's dragged from libgcc like `__udivmodsi4` and all of its dependencies.

Comment: And also notice, that for v9 up to including v12.2, code size and execution time might be bloated  due to [PR90706](https://gcc.gnu.org/PR90706). For example, for `is_udiv24_by_3` with `-O2 -mmcu=atmega8515`, v11.3 reports 64 bytes while v8 and v14 (master) will report 26 bytes. Stack usage and register pressure is also higher due to PR90706.

Comment: OK, in *`uint8_t` variant from avr-gcc 12.2.0* the `clr r1` looks owed to GCC sticking with r1 for __zero_reg__, but doesn't `cpi r0, lo8(86)` allow dropping `mov r25, r0` for one word&cycle less?

Comment: @greybeard Looks that way, yes. And the gcc ABI defining `__zero_reg__` as a register which the CPU does not clobber all the time (e.g.`r2`) would have saved the `clr r1` as well.

Answer (score 1):

What about AVRs without a MUL instruction?

```
; predicate: return in r24 (GCC AVR ABI)
;   1 if value n in r24 on entry is a multiple of 3 (divisible by 3),
;   0 otherwise
; clobbers r25 as allowed by ABI
isMultipleOf3:
    mov     r25, r24    ; by nibbles: high low
    swap    r25         ; by nibbles:  low high
    add     r24, r25    ; lo8(((low + high nibble)*17))
    mov     r25, r24    ; high nibble is congruent nibble sum mod 15 (hence 3)
                        ;  low one may be smaller by 1 - wrapping from 0 to xF
    add     r24, r24    ; shift up by 1... 
    add     r24, r24    ; ...2 bit positions
    add     r24, r25    ; b7b6 congruent n mod 3 (wish I understood *why*)
    cpi     r24, 64     ; b7b6 divisible by 3 if b7 = b6: 0xc0 <= r24 < 0x40
    ldi     r24, 0
    brpl    leave
    ldi     r24, 1
leave:
    ret                 ; 11 cycles "+ ret"
```

I tested this exhaustively even before coding it in assembly
- or thinking I fully understand it:

```py
def swap(n):
    """ swap least significant 4 bits
         with the next more significant quadruple. """
    return (n << 4 | (n >> 4))&255

def mod3(n):
    """ return n % 3. """
    n = (n + swap(n))&255
    n = n + ((n << 2)&255)
    n &= 255
    n >>= 6
    if n == 3:
        n = 0
    return n

if __name__ == '__main__':
    for n in range(256):
        if mod3(n) != n%3:
            print("n:", n, mod3(n), "!=", n%3)
```

and using Atmel Studio's (sic) simulation.
Passed successfully.

Eerily, the value manipulations strongly resemble multiplying it first by 17 and then by 5, by 85 all told. Just the same as other approaches substituting division by 3 by multiplication with the multiplicative inverse:
01010101 base two, 85 base ten.

---

For arguments bigger than a single register, use `x%3 == (x%255)%3` to first reduce to above simple case: put

```
is_udiv32_by_3:
    add     r24, r22
    adc     r24, __zero_reg__
is_udiv24_by_3:
    add     r24, r23
    adc     r24, __zero_reg__
is_udiv16_by_3:
    add     r24, r25
    adc     r24, __zero_reg__
is_udiv8_by_3:
```

before and just fall into `isMultipleOf3`. And yes, the prefix for just `is_udiv32_by_3` can be just one `add`+3`adc`, but this shifts size&time to the 24&16 bit variants.

Comment: Should work much the same way on any CPU providing 8-bit arithmetic including a nibble SWAP.

Comment: Can you say anything about how / why this works?  I see how a nibble swap is similar to `x + (x<<4) = x*17` (or the same for small integers, less than 16), but it's been a while since I looked at the fast divisibility tests so it's unclear why multiplying by `17 * 5` is relevant for checking divisibility by 3.  Does this work for all 256 possible `u8` input values, or only `0..15` where `swap` is a multiply by 16 that leaves the low half zero?

Comment: It started with an attempt to compute "congruent nibble sum %15" - it occurred to me that when *not* clearing at least one half the half carry (c₄) would be identical to the final carry (c₇ = C), the high nibble already containing it added in where subsequently to clear&add it would still have to be added. I tinkered around some finding I could generate the ≡sum%3 of that nibble's halfs in the uppermost bit pair just as well as in s₅s₄ - again without any masking.

Comment: Thanks.  Those comments would be a good addition to the answer, especially the fact that you have exhaustively tested it.