# Divisiblity by 5 without using % and / operator

Tags: c, algorithm

**How to check whether a number is divisible by 5 or not  without using % and / operator?**
I want a quickest algorithm for this problem.

I tried subtracting 5 from the number until I get 0 or a negative number. 0 means divisible by 5, negative means not divisible by 5.
But for a big number this will take too much time.

Comment: Great!  Why do you need to do this?  What have you tried so far?

Comment: Cast number into a string, extract last “character” and see whether it’s a 0 or 5 – or something else …?

Comment: @Oli Charlesworth -subtracting 5 with the number until i get 0 or negative number.
0 means divisible by 5,negative means not divisible by 5.but for a big number it will take too much time.

Comment: You should at least try to put some solution in the post, to eliminate some potentially useless answers and also show your effort.

Comment: @user2484070: There is no mechanism that is going to be as fast as simply doing `%`.  So I would suggest using `%`!

Comment: +1 The questing is not clear, and probably the OP wants someone to do their homework, but we had some good answer that may be very helpful for people that have this as a real issue.

Comment: @Jonatan Goebel - this question is a real issue for me,i was tried hard but not able to think good solution.

Comment: If is a real issue, you need to give us more information about what you are doing. The `fastest` algorithm is platform dependent, so we cannot help you if we do not know exactly what you want to do.

Comment: `(x * 0xCCCCCCCD) <= 0x33333333)` (if `x` is an `uint32_t`)

Comment: Divisibility by non-powers-of-2 gets somewhat interesting with none of fast division, remainder, or multiplication.

Answer (score 12, accepted):

A good starting point is to look into how division can be accomplished with multiplication and bit-shifts.  [This question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/5558492/divide-by-10-using-bit-shifts) is one place to look.

In particular, you can follow the attached post to hit upon the following strategy. First, "divide by 5" using multiplication and bit-shifts:

```
 int32_t div5(int32_t dividend) {
     int64_t invDivisor = 0x33333333;
     return 1 + (int32_t) ((invDivisor * dividend) >> 32);
 }
```

Then, take the result and multiply by 5:

```
int result = div5(dividend) * 5;
```

Then, `result == dividend` if and only `dividend` is divisible by 5.

```
if(result == dividend) {
    // dividend is divisible by 5
}
else {
    // dividend is not divisible by 5
}
```

Comment: You have to run this in a loop if say, the dividend is `5^5` right? I guess that's still a pretty good runtime.

Comment: @roliu: No, no loop. The result of `div5(3125)` will be `625`, which multiplied by `5` is `3125` which is equal to the dividend which says `3125` is divisible by `5`. Note the result of `div5(3125 + 1)` will be `625` but multiplied by `5` gives `3125` which is not `3125 + 1` which says `3125 + 1` is not divisible by `5`.

Comment: This formula gives an approximation, int fact, it will return `num/5 - 1`. So you need a `+ 1` in the return statement. This is valid only for the special case where the divisor is 5.

Comment: @Jason Oh right. For some reason I read `dividend` as `quotient`... not really sure why. So basically this can be summed up as `x / 5 * 5 = x` (with integer division) iff `x % 5 = 0`. And then you replace integer division with fanciness.

Answer (score 6):

There are two reasons I can see for wanting such an algorithm: (1) homework, or (2) writing efficient code for a microcontroller which does not have efficient division instructions.  Assuming your reason is the second, but allowing for the possibility that it might be the first, I won't give you a full solution, but will suggest that if you divide your number into chunks that are a multiple of four bits each, the sum of all those chunks will be divisible by five only if the original number was; note that when performing such computation you must either avoid overflows or else add to your result the number of overflows that have occurred.  I don't know any efficient way to do the latter in C, but in many machine languages it is easy.  As a simple example, on the 8051 if one had a 32-bit integer, one could so something like:

```
    mov a,Number   ; Byte 0
    add a,Number+1 ; Byte 1
    adc a,Number+2 ; Byte 2, plus carry from last add
    adc a,Number+3 ; Byte 3, plus carry from last add
    adc a,#0       ; Add in carry, if any (might overflow)
    adc a,#0       ; Add in carry, if any (can't overflow)
```

Note that in the machine code, adding the carries back into the number is much faster than performing 16-bit math would be.

Once the value has been reduced to the range 0-255, one could add the upper four bits to the lower 4 bits to get a value in the range 0 to 30.  One could either test for the seven such values that are multiples of five, or work to reduce the number of possible values further [e.g. if the value is at least 15, subtract 15; if at least 10, subtract 10; if 5, subtract five; if zero, it's a multiple of five].

Comment: @OliCharlesworth: What is the value of (16%5)?  What is the value of (16%5) squared?  Cubed?  Raised to the 492nd power?  What is the value of 255%5?  Making a carry add one to a value instead of 256 will cause the value to be 255 less after each overflow than it would be if the carry added 256.  What's the value of 255%5?

Comment: Aha, yes, that makes sense.  (a+16)%5 == (a+1)%5.  Good stuff!

Comment: I find the overflow argument in the code comments convincing, if not stringent. "Working backwards", the result of `adc  A, Number+3` may look as large as 0x1ff, necessitating both `adc  A, #0`. But working forwards, A(and carry) will contain at least one zero bit starting with the result of `add  A, Number+1` - here for no carry being added in, in bytes to follow for a zero having been *somewhere*.

Answer (score 3):

Let's represent the number in base 2. We have:

```
abcdefgh*101 = ABCDEFGHIJ
```

or

```
+abcdefgh00
+  abcdefgh
 ----------
 ABCDEFGHIJ
```

We are given `ABCDEFGHIJ` and want to find `abcdefgh`.

If you alternately - and + `ABCDEFGH` with its successive rightshift-by-2, you will get...

```
+  ABCDEFGH
-    ABCDEF
+      ABCD
-        AB
-----------
+  abcdefgh
+    abcdef
-    abcdef
-      abcd
+      abcd
+        ab
-        ab
-----------
   abcdefgh
```

The answer!

Comment: When you have the division result you can multiply it back with 5 to check the remainder

Answer (score 2):

It finally got unlocked, so I can explain my comment, which incidentally turns out to generate better code than GCC does for `x % 5 == 0`. See [here](http://gcc.godbolt.org), fill in

```
#include <stdint.h>
bool divisible_by_5(uint32_t x)
{
   return x % 5 == 0;
}
bool divisible_by_5_fast(uint32_t x)
{
   return x * 0xCCCCCCCD <= 0x33333333;
}
```

I'll assume unsigned input, because the OP suggested an algorithm that only works with positive input. This method can be extended to signed input, but it's a little messy.

`0xCCCCCCCD` is the [modular multiplicative inverse](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Modular_multiplicative_inverse) of 5, modulo 2<sup>32</sup>. Multiplying a multiple of k (for example, `n * k`) by the (modular) multiplicative inverse is equivalent to dividing by k, because

```
(n * k) * inv(k) =
// use associativity
n * (k * inv(k)) =
// use definition of multiplicative inverse
n * 1 =
// multiplicative identity
n
```

Modulo powers of two, a number has a modular multiplicative inverse iff it is odd.

Since multiplying by an odd number is invertible and is actually a bijection, it can't map any non-multiples of k to the 0 - (2<sup>32</sup>-1)/k range.

So when it's outside that range, it can't have been a multiple of k.

`0x33333333` is (2<sup>32</sup>-1)/5, so if `x * 0xCCCCCCCD` higher, `x` can't have been a multiple of 5.

Comment: [Faster remainders when the divisor is a constant: beating compilers and libdivide](https://lemire.me/blog/2019/02/08/faster-remainders-when-the-divisor-is-a-constant-beating-compilers-and-libdivide/)

Comment: @phuclv it's a different technique, but there may be some deep and interesting reason why they look so similar. The method I show uses only narrow multiplication, but on the other hand cannot easily be adapted to give the remainder or quotient in cases where the remainder isn't zero and does not immediately apply to even divisors (there is a variant with a rotate for that)

Comment: `turns out to generate better code than GCC does for x % 5 == 0` for such comparisons, I find it fair to include "-O3" in the compiler options.

Comment: This code assumes `INT_MAX == INT32_MAX`.  You might want to add a cast: `return (uint32_t)(x * 0xCCCCCCCD) <= 0x33333333;`

Answer (score 1):

In decimal, a number is divisible by 3 or 9 if **the sum of the digits is divisible by 3 or 9**

The same applies to *any divisors of `b - 1`* in ***base b***. For example we can sum the digits in base 16 and take modulo 3, 5 or 15 to get the number modulo 3, 5 or 15. See [How to find x mod 15 without using any Arithmetic Operations?](https://stackoverflow.com/q/6660376/995714)

In fact we can check divisibility by 5 in any base 2<sup>4k</sup> like 16, 256, 4096...

Using that property we have the following solution

```
unsigned mod5(unsigned x) {
    unsigned mod = 0;
    while (x) {
        mod += x & 0x0F;
        x >>= 4;
    }
    while (mod >= 15)
    {
        if (mod == 15) return 0;
        mod = (mod >> 4) + (mod & 0x0F);
    }
    return mod;   
}
```

Or it can be further optimized [like this](https://stackoverflow.com/a/3897528/995714) using a bit lookup table in the last step

```
unsigned isDivisibleBy5(unsigned x) {
    x = (x >> 16) + (x & 0xffff);
    x = (x >> 8)  + (x & 0x00ff);
    x = (x >> 4)  + (x & 0x000f);
    return (0x1084210842108421ULL >> x) & 1;
}
```

Comment: Argue with *x ≡ 1 mod b* → *x ≡ 1 mod bⁿ* for all *0 < n*?

Comment: @greybeard what do you mean? if *2ᵏ ≡ 1 (mod b)* then *2ⁿᵏ  ≡ 1 (mod b)*, which means [*each digit the base-2ᵏ number contributes the digit 1 to the mod b sum*](https://stackoverflow.com/a/26047426/995714). I'm not really good at congruence math but [here's an easier proof without modulo arithmetic](https://math.stackexchange.com/a/1676920/90333)

Comment: Exactly. If you don't feel like it, leave it out of the answer. I'm hardly one to claim algebra as my 1st language.

Comment: @chqrlie that's an oversight because the linked answer used `!= 0` and I converted it

Comment: I don't think you need the `&`s before `&0xf`.

Answer (score 0):

Add all the bytes and check (by table look-up) if the sum is divisible by 5.

Comment: Actually that works, because 256 % 5 = 1, and therefore the "multiplier" for each digit is 1 (ie, just add them). If it hadn't been 1, the algorithm with a digital sum still works, but you'd have to scale every digit by some amount.

Comment: @harold was thinking `bits`. Would be really happy to +1 this if Egor edits it (-1 locked).

Answer (score 0):

Keep subtracting by multiples of 5 like 50, 500,100, etc. Start with big numbers. If the result goes in negative then subtract with a smaller number number until you reach 0. Otherwise the number is not divisible.

Comment: (A bit more organised this is one division algorithm.)

Answer (score 0):

```
bool trythis(int number){
  Int start = number;
  Do{
    start = start - 5;
  } while (start > 5)

  If (start == 5 || start == 0) {
    Return true;
  } else return false;
}
```

Comment: While this code may answer the question, providing additional context regarding how and/or why it solves the problem would improve the answer's long-term value.

Answer (score -3):

Typecast or convert to a string, then see if the final character is a 5 or 0.