# How to check if a number is a multiple of 6?

Tags: algorithm, binary

I would like an alogrithm that would use only shift, add or subtract operations to find whether a number is a multiple of 6.  So, basically just binary operations.

So far I think I should logical right shift the number twice to divide by 4 and then subtract 6 once from it.  But I know something is wrong with my approach and cannot figure out what.

Comment: You can keep subtracting 6 from the number and see that it gets to zero. If the result is less than zero, then it's not divisible by 6

Comment: Not exactly efficient, but you can implement a modulus function using only subtraction.

Comment: If this is being used in a real program:  don't do this.  Just use `num % 6`, and let the compiler figure out what's the fastest method.  More likely than not, simply using the CPU's `mod` operation will be faster than any bit-hacks you come up with.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

how about keep subtracting the number by 6 until it reaches zero.
If you get zero the number is divisible by 6 otherwise not.
OR
keep dividing the number by 2 (shift operation on binary) until the number is less than 12.
then subtract 6 from it . If less than zero  (not divisible )
if zero divisible.
if not subtract 3 
 If less than zero  (not divisible )
if zero divisible.

Answer (score 7):

1) Simple `(N & 1) == 0` to check if number is divisible by 2.

2) Use the Bit hack answer (from [This](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3421609/check-if-a-number-is-divisible-by-3) thread. )to check for divisibility by 3.

If both are true, your number is divisible by 6.

Comment: Hmmph.  Beat me by a minute, but I linked to [the hack](http://stackoverflow.com/a/3421654/487339) directly. :^)

Answer (score 0):

```
Reference: http://wiki.answers.com/Q/How_can_you_tell_if_a_number_is_a_multiple_of_6

It is a multiple of six if BOTH of the following statements are true:
1) The last digit (ones place) is 0, 2, 4, 6, or 8.
2) When you add all the digits together, you get a multiple of 3.


Reference: http://wiki.answers.com/Q/How_can_you_tell_if_a_number_is_a_multiple_of_3

1) Start with a number N. 
2) Sum the digits of the number, and get M. 
3) If M is larger than 10, set N=M and return to stage 2.
4) Otherwise, M is now smaller than 10. If M is 0,3,6 or 9, then N is a multiple of 3
```

Comment: Now explain, How will you add all the digits without using division?

Comment: Reference: http://wiki.answers.com/Q/How_can_you_tell_if_a_number_is_a_multiple_of_6

Comment: Dude, how would you sum all the digits without using mod or div or converting it to string?

Answer (score 0):

You could try implementing a division algorithm with the primitive operations available to you. The basic long-division algorithm from 4th grade might be enough (just do things in base 2 instead of base 10, with bitshifting instead of multiplication)

Answer (score 0):

OK. This is how I would go about it (just a first thought) :

A multiple of 6 is both a multiple of 2 and 3, so it should satisfy the divisibility criteria of 2 and 3 at the same time... So...

- **Check divisibility by 2** :

  1. Right shift the number
  2. If remainder>1, repeat 1.
  3. If remainder=1, then FALSE, else continue.

     *Checking the divisibility by 2, could obviously be also implemented by (N & 1 == 0), as stated above. This simply checks the last digit of N's binary representation : if it's 1, N is odd (thus NOT divisible by 2), if it's 0, it's perfectly divisible...*
- **Check divisibility by 3** :

  1. Substract 3.
  2. If remainder>3, repeat 1.
  3. If remainder>0, then FALSE, else TRUE.

Answer (score 0):

If we extend the range of operations to "bit-masking" and "bit-shifting", it's simple.

As quite a few have stated, divisibility by two is equivalent to `(n & 1) == 0`. Divisbility by 3 is (relatively) easy in binary. Initialize an accumulator `a` to 0, then repeat `a += (n & 3); n = (n >> 2);` until n is 0. If (and only if) a is 3 is n divisible by 3.