# FPGA spartan 3 - X mod 3 inside combinatorial process without clock

Tags: vhdl, fpga, modelsim, xilinx-ise

I am working on a project which one part pivots around finding X mod 3 with and FPGA spartan 3 (Xilinx),
inside a combinatorial process.
in fact in this project there are some other modules which are sequential, before this ALU module.
but inside the ALU module, it is not allowed to use sequential process.
so I tried to use one method from [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/844867/check-if-a-number-is-divisible-by-3):

> Here is an simple way to do it by hand. Since 1 = 22 mod 3, we get 1 =
>   22n mod 3 for every positive integer. Furthermore 2 = 22n+1 mod 3.
>   Hence one can determine if an integer is divisible by 3 by counting
>   the 1 bits at odd bit positions, multiply this number by 2, add the
>   number of 1-bits at even bit posistions add them to the result and
>   check if the result is divisible by 3.
>
> Example: 57<sub>10</sub>=111001<sub>2</sub>. There are 2 bits at odd positions, and 2 bits
>   at even positions. 2*2 + 2 = 6 is divisible by 3. Hence 57 is
>   divisible by 3.

I have posted my codes down there. the problem is that after I concatenate the odd bits and even bits in two different signals:

```
        mod_un_t1 <= A(6) & A(4)& A(2) & A(0);
        mod_un_t2 <= A(7) & A(5)& A(3) & A(1);
```

I lose all data and no if statement works after that. I simulated my code with a  test-bench. but it always gives:

```
result <= "00000000";
```

I have tested it and I found out that no data would be pass down after that concatenation.
I cannot use sequential network and count-up and count-down methods, or shift register method which all of them work with clk and sequential process.

Could any one please help me, to solve the problem in my code, and if anyone has a better method or better implementation way let me be through this nowhere!!!

and this is my code:

```
library ieee;
use ieee.std_logic_1164.all;
use ieee.numeric_std.all;
Use Ieee.std_logic_unsigned.all;

entity ALU is
   port ( A          : in  std_logic_vector (7 downto 0);   -- Input A
          B          : in  std_logic_vector (7 downto 0);   -- Input B
          FN         : in  std_logic_vector (3 downto 0);   -- ALU functions provided by the ALU_Controller (see the lab manual)
          result       : out std_logic_vector (7 downto 0);   -- ALU output (unsigned binary)
           overflow   : out std_logic;                       -- '1' if overflow ocurres, '0' otherwise 
           sign       : out std_logic                        -- '1' if the result is a negative value, '0' otherwise
        );
end ALU;

architecture behavioral of ALU is

signal mod_un_t1: std_logic_vector (3 downto 0);
signal mod_un_t2: std_logic_vector (3 downto 0);
signal mod_un_t3: std_logic_vector (3 downto 0);
signal mod_un_t4: std_logic_vector (3 downto 0);
signal mod_unsigned: std_logic_vector (3 downto 0);

signal mod_si_t1: std_logic_vector (3 downto 0);
signal mod_si_t2: std_logic_vector (3 downto 0);
signal mod_si_t3: std_logic_vector (3 downto 0);
signal mod_si_t4: std_logic_vector (3 downto 0);
signal mod_signed: std_logic_vector (3 downto 0);

begin
   process ( FN, A, B , result_tmp)
   begin
        result <= (others => '0');
        mod_un_t1 <= (others => '0');
        mod_un_t2 <= (others => '0');
        mod_un_t3 <= (others => '0');
        mod_un_t4 <= (others => '0');
        mod_unsigned <= (others => '0');
        mod_si_t1 <= (others => '0');
        mod_si_t2 <= (others => '0');
        mod_si_t3 <= (others => '0');
        mod_si_t4 <= (others => '0');
        mod_signed <= (others => '0');

        if (FN = "0100") then -- Unsigned (A) mod 3
            mod_un_t1 <= A(6) & A(4)& A(2) & A(0);
            mod_un_t2 <= A(7) & A(5)& A(3) & A(1);

            if(mod_un_t1= "1111") then
              mod_un_t3 <= "1000";
            elsif(mod_un_t1 = "1110" or mod_un_t1 = "1101" or  mod_un_t1 = "1011" or mod_un_t1 = "0111") then
                mod_un_t3 <= "0110";
            elsif(mod_un_t1 = "1100" or mod_un_t1 = "1010" or mod_un_t1 = "1001" or mod_un_t1 = "0110" or mod_un_t1 = "0101" or mod_un_t1 = "0011") then
                mod_un_t3 <= "0100";
            elsif(mod_un_t1 = "0001" or mod_un_t1 = "0010" or mod_un_t1 = "0100" or mod_un_t1 = "1000") then
                mod_un_t3 <= "0010";
            elsif (mod_un_t1 = "0000") then
                mod_un_t3 <= "0000";
            end if;

            if (mod_un_t2 = "1111") then
                mod_un_t4 <= "0100";
            elsif (mod_un_t2 = "1110" or mod_un_t2 = "1101" or mod_un_t2 = "1011" or mod_un_t2 = "0111") then
                mod_un_t4 <= "0011";
            elsif(mod_un_t2 = "1100" or mod_un_t2 = "1010" or mod_un_t2 = "1001" or mod_un_t2 = "0110" or mod_un_t2 = "0101" or mod_un_t2 = "0011") then
                mod_un_t4 <= "0010";
            elsif(mod_un_t2 = "0001" or mod_un_t2 = "0010" or mod_un_t2 = "0100" or mod_un_t2 = "1000") then
                mod_un_t4 <= "0001";
            elsif(mod_un_t2 = "0000") then
                mod_un_t4 <= "0000";
            end if;

            mod_unsigned <= mod_un_t3 + mod_un_t4;

            if  (mod_unsigned = "0010" or  mod_unsigned = "0101" or mod_unsigned ="0111" or mod_unsigned = "1010") then
                result <= "00000001";
            elsif (mod_unsigned = "0001" or mod_unsigned = "0100" or mod_unsigned = "1000" or mod_unsigned = "1011") then
                result <= "00000010";
            elsif (mod_unsigned = "0000" or mod_unsigned = "0011" or mod_unsigned = "0110" or mod_unsigned = "1001") then
                result <= "00000000";
            end if;
        end if;

   end process;
end behavioral;
```

Answer (score 1):

The signals that don't seem to have assignments are missing from the process sensitivity list. They could otherwise be variables, allowing their use during the current simulation cycle without generating delta cycles because signal assignment doesn't take effect until the end or the current simulation cycle.

Candidates for variables appear to be:

```
signal mod_un_t1: std_logic_vector (3 downto 0);
signal mod_un_t2: std_logic_vector (3 downto 0);
signal mod_un_t3: std_logic_vector (3 downto 0);
signal mod_un_t4: std_logic_vector (3 downto 0);
signal mod_unsigned: std_logic_vector (3 downto 0);

signal mod_si_t1: std_logic_vector (3 downto 0);
signal mod_si_t2: std_logic_vector (3 downto 0);
signal mod_si_t3: std_logic_vector (3 downto 0);
signal mod_si_t4: std_logic_vector (3 downto 0);
signal mod_signed: std_logic_vector (3 downto 0);
```

These declarations could be changed to object class variable and moved to the process (before the `begin`). The signal assignments for them (`<=`) would be switched to variable assignment (`:=`).

You could simply put those that show up on the right hand side of an assignment  in the sensitivity list, but that would cause extra delta cycles.

If there's a reason to keep them signals you could consider breaking your process up into multiple processes and/or other concurrent statements.

There's a `result_tmp` in the sensitivity list that doesn't have a declaration or an assignment in the code you've shown.

***... could you please also give a short example for breaking the process up into multiple processes and/or other concurrent statements?***

```
Aarchitecture foo of ALU is

    signal mod_un_t1: std_logic_vector (3 downto 0);
    signal mod_un_t2: std_logic_vector (3 downto 0);
    signal mod_un_t3: std_logic_vector (3 downto 0);
    signal mod_un_t4: std_logic_vector (3 downto 0);
    signal mod_unsigned: std_logic_vector (3 downto 0);

    signal mod_si_t1: std_logic_vector (3 downto 0);
    signal mod_si_t2: std_logic_vector (3 downto 0);
    signal mod_si_t3: std_logic_vector (3 downto 0);
    signal mod_si_t4: std_logic_vector (3 downto 0);
    signal mod_signed: std_logic_vector (3 downto 0);
    -- dummy 
    signal result_tmp: std_logic_vector(7 downto 0);

begin

    -- Concurrent signal assignments - these are just wires
    mod_un_t1 <= A(6) & A(4)& A(2) & A(0);
    mod_un_t2 <= A(7) & A(5)& A(3) & A(1); 

UNPROC1:
    process (FN, mod_un_t1)
    begin
    if FN = "0100" then
        case mod_un_t1 is
            when "0000" =>
                mod_un_t3 <= "0000";
            when "0001" | "0010" | "0100" | "1000" =>
                mod_un_t3 <= "0010";
            when "1100" | "1010" | "1001" | "0110" =>
                mod_un_t3 <= "0100";
            when "1110" | "1101" | "1011" | "0111" =>
                mod_un_t3 <= "0100";
            when others =>
            end case;
    else
    --
    end if;
end process;

UNPROC2:
    process (FN, mod_un_t2)
    begin
    if FN = "0100" then 
        if mod_un_t2 = "1111" then
            mod_un_t4 <= "0100";
        elsif mod_un_t2 = "1110" or mod_un_t2 = "1101" or mod_un_t2 = "1011" or mod_un_t2 = "0111" then
            mod_un_t4 <= "0011";
        elsif mod_un_t2 = "1100" or mod_un_t2 = "1010" or mod_un_t2 = "1001" or mod_un_t2 = "0110" or mod_un_t2 = "0101" or mod_un_t2 = "0011" then
            mod_un_t4 <= "0010";
        elsif mod_un_t2 = "0001" or mod_un_t2 = "0010" or mod_un_t2 = "0100" or mod_un_t2 = "1000" then
            mod_un_t4 <= "0001";
        elsif mod_un_t2 = "0000" then
            mod_un_t4 <= "0000";
        end if;
    else
        --
    end if;
end process;

ALU_PROC:  -- keep all the arithemetic operations in one process
    process (FN, mod_un_t3, mod_un_t4)
    begin
        if FN = "0100" then 
             mod_unsigned <= mod_un_t3 + mod_un_t4;
        else 

        end if;
    end process;

OUT_PROC: -- keep all the result assignment in one process
process (FN, mod_unsigned)
    begin
        if FN = "0100" then 
            if  mod_unsigned = "0010" or  mod_unsigned = "0101" or mod_unsigned ="0111" or mod_unsigned = "1010" then
                result <= "00000001";
            elsif mod_unsigned = "0001" or mod_unsigned = "0100" or mod_unsigned = "1000" or mod_unsigned = "1011" then
                result <= "00000010";
            elsif mod_unsigned = "0000" or mod_unsigned = "0011" or mod_unsigned = "0110" or mod_unsigned = "1001" then
                result <= "00000000";
            else 
            --
            end if;
        end if;
    end process;

end architecture foo;
```

Comment: @ David Koontz, Your answer gave quite the result that I need. Thank you so much. It was really a big help. BTW, the result_tmp is for another arithmatic operation in my designed ALU.

Comment: @ David Koontz, could you please also give a short example for breaking the process up into multiple processes and/or other concurrent statements??

Comment: Note you don't have full coverage for binary values in if statement conditions, which means inferred latches.

Comment: What should I do so? do you mean I had better choose when/case or when/select instead or  I should assign a dummy value to my result and add an else at the end of all if statements??