# How to divide an integer by 3 using binary operations

Tags: binary, integer-division

Similar question: [How to know if a binary number divides by 3?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/39385971/how-to-know-if-a-binary-number-divides-by-3)

But how to actually divide a number by 3, efficiently, using only binary operations?

Answer (score 0):

The main idea is the following observation:

```
1/3 = 1/4 + 1/16 + 1/64 + ...
```

and we keep in mind that division by 4 is a simple binary operation (two bit shifts).
Now, since we're dealing with integers, which may not be dividable by powers of 4, we have to make proper modifications. Let x_0 be an integer dividable by 3. We have:

```
x_0 = 4*q_0 + r_0
```

where q_0 = x_0 // 4 and r_0 = x_0 % 4, or in other words,

```
q_0 = x_0 >> 2, r_0 = x_0 & 3
```

For this q_0, we have

```
x_0 - 3*q_0 = q_0 + r_0
```

We add q_0 to an accumulating sum, and now we're left to divide x_1 := q_0 + r_0, which we know is dividable by 3, and is smaller (by roughly two bits) than x_0. Iterating this idea while x_k > 3, the induced sequence

```
q_0 + q_1 + ... + q_k
```

adds up to the desired result, x_0 / 3.

So as for operations, we had: bit-shifts, AND and addition. Additions are simply implemented with binary operations, using AND and XOR. Here is some code:

```
def binary_sum(a, b):
    
    while True:
        
        add = a ^ b         # '^' is XOR
        carry = a & b
        if carry == 0:
            break
        else:
            a = add
            b = carry << 1
    
    return add
        


def bin_division_by_3(x):
     
    sum = 1

    while x > 3:
        q, r = x >> 2, x & 3
        sum = binary_sum(sum, q)
        x = binary_sum(q, r)

    return sum
```